# Error "No overload matches this call" on component "MenuItem"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

using the following code, I get an error "No overload matches this call" shown from my IDE on my code.
Somewhere else I use a similar code but have a string as value for the value property of MenuItem where I don't get an error.

What does the error mean? What do I do wrong?

Code

```
<FormControl fullWidth>
    <InputLabel id="my-input-label">my-input</InputLabel>
    <Select
        labelId="my-input-label"
        id="my-element"
        value={value}
        label="yes/no"
        defaultValue={true}
        onChange={onChange}
    >
        <MenuItem value={true}>yes</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={false}>no</MenuItem>
    </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the `MenuItem` value. It is `LiHTMLAttributes` prop, and it only allows `string | string[] | number`. You can change the `true/false` values to `yes/no` and can easily convert into boolean.

```
const [input, setInput] = React.useState("no");
...
 <FormControl fullWidth>
   <InputLabel id="my-input-label">my-input</InputLabel>
    <Select
      labelId="my-input-label"
      id="my-element"
      value={input}
      label="yes/no"
      onChange={handleChange}
     >
       <MenuItem value={"yes"}>yes</MenuItem>
       <MenuItem value={"no"}>no</MenuItem>
   </Select>
 </FormControl>
```

Also, you can set the default value at the `useState` declaration. Here is the codesandbox link

[image: Edit%20SOQ-71499278-MUI-Select]